# How can I listen to the height change of a div?

Tags: javascript

I have a container div whose height can change when new elements loaded in it or because the user resize the screen (it is responsive with flex-wrap).
I need to know when the height of the div change to then execute a JS function. What event can I had with addEventListener? Or maybe I read about Observers but not sure this is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

> The `ResizeObserver` interface reports changes to the dimensions of an Element's content or border box, or the bounding box of an `SVGElement`.

It's supported by [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/resizeobserver).

[image]